# Angular 1.6 - Best way to bind an array of objects to checkbox inputs via ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular1.6

Having this table row in mind, I'm trying to dynamically enable/disable the appropriate checkboxes:

```js
function enableTheRoles(data){
  var myRoles = [
    {role1: true, name: "Role One",   enabled: true},
    {role2: false, name: "Role Two",   enabled: false},
    {role3: true, name: "Role Three", enabled: true},
    {role4: false, name: "Role Four",  enabled: false},
    {role5: true, name: "Role Five",   enabled: true},
    {role6: false, name: "Role Six",   enabled: false},
    {role7: true, name: "Role Seven", enabled: true},
    {role8: false, name: "Role Eight",  enabled: false},
    {role9: true, name: "Role Nine", enabled: true},
    {role10: false, name: "Role Ten",  enabled: false}
  ];

}
```

```html
<tr>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="role1" ng-model="ctrl.data.roles.role1" />&nbsp;Role One
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="role2" ng-model="ctrl.data.roles.role2" />&nbsp;Role Two
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="role3" ng-model="ctrl.data.roles.role3" />&nbsp;Role Three
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="role4" ng-model="ctrl.data.roles.role4" />&nbsp;Role Four<
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="role5" ng-model="ctrl.data.roles.role5" />&nbsp;Role Five
</td>
<td>role six</td>
<td>role seven</td>
<td>role eight</td>
</tr>
```

So far I've managed to iterate the source data (coming back from an Angular service), and create a new array entitled `myRoles`.

I'd like to now tie the `myRoles` array to the `checkbox` inputs on my view, and therefore enable/disable accordingly.

So in other words, if the "Role One" checkbox should be `enabled`, then `ng-model=ctrl.data.roles.role1` should pick up the `enabled` property from the `myRoles` array.

Perhaps iterating thru ng-model ?

Any advice is appreciated. In the meantime, I will research ...

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `ng-repeat` directive as demonstrated here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller('appController', function($scope) {
      $scope.myRoles = [
        {role1: true, name: "Role One",   enabled: true},
        {role2: false, name: "Role Two",   enabled: false},
        {role3: true, name: "Role Three", enabled: true},
        {role4: false, name: "Role Four",  enabled: false}
      ];
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="role in myRoles">
          <input type="checkbox" name="role1" ng-model="role.enabled" />&nbsp;{{role.name}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE Based on responses:

Are you after the layout to be this:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10
```

or this:

```
1  4  7  10
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

For the first layout this will work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Example</title>
    <style>
    .role {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 25%;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller('appController', function($scope) {
      window.x = $scope.myRoles = [
        {role1: true, name: "Role One",   enabled: true},
        {role2: false, name: "Role Two",   enabled: false},
        {role3: true, name: "Role Three", enabled: true},
        {role4: false, name: "Role Four",  enabled: false},
        {role1: true, name: "Role Five",   enabled: false},
        {role2: false, name: "Role Six",   enabled: true},
        {role3: true, name: "Role Seven", enabled: true},
        {role4: false, name: "Role Eight",  enabled: false},
        {role1: true, name: "Role Nine",   enabled: false},
        {role2: false, name: "Role Ten",   enabled: false}
      ];
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <span class="role" ng-repeat="role in myRoles">
      <input type="checkbox" name="role1" ng-model="role.enabled" />&nbsp;{{role.name}}
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now to make it more interested, in turns out I have 10 total roles coming back from service. So I need to cleanly display only four <td> elements per row. I suppose I could split up my array into 3 separate ones, then have three `<tr ng-repeat>` sections...but it doesn't seem efficient...

Comment: Instead of putting everything in a table you can just place it into `<span>` tags and it will wrap automatically. If you need more precision then just allowing it to wrap based on screen width, then it will take more that just using `<span>` tags.

Comment: Based on your answer, I would say that it works. However, of course now I'm challenged with create three separate `<tr>` elements for a clean-looking table.Thanks.